# Users moderate own comments

Tags: comments, review

Im putting together a portfolio site and have come across something that i would like to implement, but im unsure of how i can set around doing it.

Basically as the site stands now (in development) the user never has (or will have) to access wp-admin to change any of their details, they can do that via a user-profile page.

Each user has a portfolio/bio page with a comments form at the bottom, what im wanting to do is make it so that any comments left on this bio page are moderated by that pages owner, ie perfect solution would be:

1) Bio page owner is notified via email that they have a new comment.

2) Bio page owner logs in and goes to user-profile page to review and then accept/decline comment, upon accepting it is then published.

Anyone have any previous experience in this, or know of a working site/plugin that i could take a look at, or just any general advice on what im trying to do.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/
This plugin is great for fine tuned control of content.  I have not, however, tried what you are requesting.  So I can only suggest it as something to look into.... I'm not sure if it gives such fine tuned control over comments....

Comment: Rev.Voodoo, just took a look at this plugin, im sure when combined with the revisionary plugin (as suggested on wordpress extends) i can get it to do what i want... Been looking 3 or 4 days for something like this and never saw either of these returned in search... many thanks,

Comment: Phew.. this is some plugin Rev.Voodoo, is there anything it doesnt do?.. once again thanks

Comment: I've only begun playing with it myself on a site.  It is definitely a good plugin to know!  Hope it's helping you out!